# using sed to change numbers in a csv file

Tags: linux

I have a csv file with 3 columns like below

> Jones Smith 656220665

I would like to convert it to

> Jones Smith 000000000

The problem i have is not all the numbers are the same length. some are 7 digits long. i can't seem to find a way to change them from their current format to 0,s and has to use `sed` and `cut`

Here is 2 of the codes i tried and tried to manipulate to suit my needs

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^_]*\)_\(.*\)/\1 \3/g'   Input_file
```

and

```
$ sed 's/\(\([^,]\+,\)\{1\}\)\([^,]\+,\)\(.*\)/\1\3\3\4/' /path/to/your/file
```

Comment: Try regex101.com then convert it to sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using sed, how about this:

```
echo 'Jones Smith 656220665' | tr '[0-9]' '0'
Jones Smith 000000000
```

For the whole file that's then:

```
tr '[0-9]' '0' < file > file.tmp
```

Edit 1:
added a sed solution:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/0/g' smith
Jones Smith 000000000
```

stil
Edit 2:

```
cat ClientData.csv > ClientData.csv.bak
sed 's/[0-9]/0/g; w ClientData.csv' ClientData.csv.bak | cut -d" " -f 1-2
```

Comment: Unfortunatly i have to use commands sed, cat & cut to acheive multiple tasks i used cut do remove a column and only print names leaving me to use sed and cat and that is making a little harder haha

Comment: Right, that can be done, too, `tr` would have been `more lightweight` ... see my edit, @Nagros

Comment: that is awesomethank you if i remove smith will that change the whole file? 
i tried to use vut to pic the column and then use your code to then change the numbers to 0's but i swear this code hates me lol 
or would cat be better i have to find away to use sed and cat -.-

Comment: That's just what I called the file ... use `Input_file` (or whatever your file is called) instead of `smith`

Comment: You are a champ thanks heaps i should be able to get the rest of the way from here thank you heaps

Comment: You're welcome =) ... feel free to accept my answer ;)

Comment: n cut to only print out the names so I have been using 
"sed 's/[0-9]/0/g'outputfile | cat > output file | cut -d , -f 1-2 outputfile "
Basically I need to have it so the output goes from sed to cat but pipe it through cut because I need to use I've tried variant ways of the above code

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, that looks like English but I can't understand a word. The `cat` in your snippet adds absolutely no value, `sed 's/[0-9]/0/g' outputfile  > "output file"`  (I quoted your "output file" because it contains a space) achieves the same result. tacking the `cut` onto that stanza won't work. Instead of describing what you did, can you try explaining the desired result?

Comment: sorry posted on my mobile didnt realise it didnt post the begining for some reason.

Ok so i need to use sed cat & cut and the out come i need is to change the numbers to 0's using sed then using cat i need to output the result to a file and using cut only print the full names from the .csv file i have but not sure how to pipe all that together

Comment: Given the commands you have at your disposal I can't see how this could be done in a single step; it two iterations are OK look at the edited answer.

Comment: yeah i cant see it either but the reply i got back was 
think about rewriting the output from sed using cat but piping it through cut.  
its got me stunned thats for sure

Comment: Can you put the brief here verbatim? I still don't see the big picture, and with the individual tasks you've mentioned so far this can't be achieved.

Comment: You found a file called ClientData.csv. You spoke to your manager and they said all the Client IDs in the file should be replaced with zeroes (000000000). You looked at the file and the Client IDs are in the file. Use sed, cat & cut as required to help you answer the questions
below.
a) What is the command line to replace all of the Client IDs in the file with zeroes? (make
a copy prior to starting so it is easy to revert back if you make a mistake or start by
outputting to a new file until you have the syntax correct.)
b) Print out a list of all the user's full names.

Comment: Doesn't say anything about doing that in a single step. Hmmm ...  from the brief I'd do the newly edited edit :)

Comment: yeah i was going to do the same but on the forums it was said it needs to be done in 1 line now B) is using cut so i thought i could use cat and sed in A) but i can not work it out either haha

Comment: I still don't see how you could do that without the use of `tee`.  Either sed writes the output to file, or outputs to stdout. You can't have both, whether you use cat or not ...

Comment: @Nagros - got it - look at the last change.

Comment: ok you are legit a legend i didnt think about .bak thank you SOOO much

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with `sed` general substitution of:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/0/g`
```

(where the `'g'` provides a global replacement of all instances of `[0-9]` with `'0'`), e.g.

```
$ echo "Jones Smith 656220665" | sed 's/[0-9]/0/g'
Jones Smith 000000000
```

Give it a shot and let me know if you have further issues.